# Retrieving and storing data from SQLite or NSMutableArrays in an iphone application

Tags: iphone, sqlite, ios5, nsmutablearray

My real Question is which of these is more efficient in terms of loading speed and cpu load for an iphone application. could you please based your answers with proofs such real results or valid references.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use SQlite if you need to store data persistently. Accessing data from memory is faster than accessing it  from file system. Since database lies on file system, NSMutableArray is faster than SQLite. The problem is you cant access data from NSMutableArray when you quit your application.

Answer (score 0):

Core Data will be your best solution.

Core Data is an object graph and persistence framework. It allows data organised by the relational entity–attribute model to be serialised into XML, binary, or SQLite stores. The data can be manipulated using higher level objects representing entities and their relationships. Core Data manages the serialised version, providing object lifecycle and object graph management, including persistence. Core Data interfaces directly with SQLite, insulating the developer from the underlying SQL. It can serialize objects into XML, Binary, or SQLite for storage. [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Core_Data)

Comment: You could improve this answer by providing some reasons for your recommendation.